# Why is blender distorting my UVs when i scale them down?

Tags: uv, distort

I've been encountering an issue with blender when scaling down my UVs. When they are first projected at full size, they look fine, but when i scale them down, the UVs start getting warped. Any idea what is causing this?

Original UVs:

[image: Original UVs]

UVs distorted after scaling them down:

[image: Distorted UVs]

Comment: I do have proportional editing and snap turned off.

Comment: I never figured out how to prevent this with the regular scaling tool. But i added the Magic UV plugin and those tools have a feature called "uniform scaling" which allowed me to scale down without distortion.